# hibernate sometimes return empty list

Tags: java, hibernate, list, return

I have strange issue with hibernate. I'm using annotated class as entity. The problem is that sometimes hibernate return empty list and after few trials it's eventually returns the data (after rebooting app). Hibernate doesn't throw any exception, no SQL select is printout to the console (normally in my app prints sql select query)

My table contain about 9000 rows.

Comment: Could you provide some of your code? I guess that maybe you are serializing the results, before JPA can lazy load the data. Are you using jersey/jaxb or some other kind of serialization?

Comment: any caches confiured?

Comment: which database server you are using ?

Comment: Will need to see code before helping you.